# Given array, write a function that finds the max and return the matching string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been given an array and need to write a function mostExpensiveItemName(items) and have it return the largest number in the array and return the items name.

Example output:

```
mostExpensiveItemName(items) //=> "Creation 3005"
```

Given array:

```
let items = [
  {
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Creation 3005",
    type: "computer",
    price: 299.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Finding Your Center",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.00
  }
]
```

What I have:

```
function mostExpensiveItemName(items) {
  if (items.length === 0) return undefined;
  let mostExpensive = items.reduce((total, items) => items.price > total.price ? items : total);

  return mostExpensive.itemName;
}
```

My solution works but I was wondering if there was a super elementary way of writing it. With a for loop or max() method

Comment: What you have seems good enough.

Comment: I'd also say that your solution is the way to go. It's short, rather easy to read (even though I'd rename `(total, items)` to `(curMax, item)`) and runs in O(n). I'd consider abstracting it one level, creating a `customMax(items, item => item.price)` method, especially if you use it in multiple occasions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try an ascending `sort` and pick the last element

```js
let items = [
  {
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99,
  },
  {
    itemName: "Creation 3005",
    type: "computer",
    price: 299.99,
  },
  {
    itemName: "Finding Your Center",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.0,
  },
]

function mostExpensiveItemName(items) {
  return (items.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price).pop() || {}).itemName
}

console.log(mostExpensiveItemName(items))
console.log(mostExpensiveItemName([]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function mostExpensiveItemName(items) {
    let counter = 0;
        //assign name to return later with conditional
    let name;
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        const e = items[i];
            /* conditional holds price value in the counter variable 
            while it cycles through the loop */
        if (e.price > counter){
            counter = e.price;
                //if true, condition also assigns name to e.itemName
            name = e.itemsName;
            }
        }
    return name;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).